# Trigger "change" event on input does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I created kind of custom checkbox's plugin for my own project.
 So I wanted to trigger `<input type="checkbox">` manually clicking on another button like this:

```
$("a#triggerButton").click(function(){
   $("input[type='checkbox']")
     .prop("checked", true)
     .triggerHandler("change");
});
```

Here is a typical example of what I'm doing: http://jsfiddle.net/fstqvq8k/3/
It seems that the event isn't triggered. I used a lot of methods but not seems to work too:

- `$("input[type='checkbox']").change();`
- `$(document).on("change", "input[type='checkbox']", function(){});`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you dynamically create your button:

```
$("#container").on("click", "#triggerButton", function() {
    $("#customCheckbox")
        .prop("checked", true)
        .trigger("change");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fstqvq8k/4/

Also from the **[Docs](http://api.jquery.com/triggerhandler/)** read:

> The .triggerHandler() method does not cause the default behavior of an event to occur (such as a form submission).

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I used the good trigger for the button but it seems that it was due to `triggerHandler()`... Btw, good job !

Answer (score 0):

You can also trigger the checkbox event like..

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click();
```